# linker can't find libraries although defined in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm quite new to work with cmake, and there is a problem I can't find the solution to:

I use the `vtk` library and specify this in the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0053 OLD)

project      (pcl-visualizer)
find_package (Qt4 REQUIRED)
find_package (VTK REQUIRED)
find_package (PCL 1.7.1 REQUIRED)

include_directories (${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories    (${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions     (${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set  (project_SOURCES main.cpp pclviewer.cpp)
set  (project_HEADERS pclviewer.h)
set  (project_FORMS   pclviewer.ui)
set  (VTK_LIBRARIES   vtkRendering vtkGraphics vtkHybrid QVTK)

QT4_WRAP_CPP (project_HEADERS_MOC   ${project_HEADERS})
QT4_WRAP_UI  (project_FORMS_HEADERS ${project_FORMS})

INCLUDE         (${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS (${QT_DEFINITIONS})

ADD_EXECUTABLE  (pcl_visualizer ${project_SOURCES}
                                ${project_FORMS_HEADERS}
                                ${project_HEADERS_MOC})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (pcl_visualizer ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

cmake also runs fine. It gives no error so I assume it can find all libraries, including the `vtk` library?

When I run `make` though, I get this error message:

```
[ 16%] Linking CXX executable pcl_visualizer
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkRendering
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkGraphics
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkHybrid
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQVTK
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkRendering
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkGraphics
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkHybrid
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQVTK
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer.dir/build.make:410: pcl_visualizer] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I installed the `vtk` library via the package manager *(pacman, I run arch linux)*, so it should be in one of the standard directories?

I checked if the right libraries are installed via `pacman -Q vtk` and it lists all needed libraries in the `/usr/lib/`` directory.

Comment: Did you install the *development* packages? Most Linux package managers divide libraries into two packages: One containing the (dynamic) library and support files needed by the library at run-time; And one package for all development files (including header files and static libraries). I haven't used Arch enough to know if it follows that, or if all is in a single package. Something to check for at least.

Comment: I checked if the relevant libraries are there, turns out they are in the */usr/lib* directory. Shouldn't cmake already complain if libraries are missing?